# Column offset lable form Ant CSS doesn't work - ReactJS

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I'm new to ReactJs - Ant Design, I want to move the label of the Form item according to the input element but it doesn't work, why the offset column doesn't work? Am I doing something wrong? What steps should I take?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './index.css';
import { Button, Form, Input, Radio } from 'antd';

type LayoutType = Parameters<typeof Form>[0]['layout'];

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [form] = Form.useForm();
  const [formLayout, setFormLayout] = useState<LayoutType>('horizontal');

  const onFormLayoutChange = ({ layout }: { layout: LayoutType }) => {
    setFormLayout(layout);
  };

  const formItemLayout =
    formLayout === 'horizontal' ? { labelCol: { span: 4 }, wrapperCol: { span: 14 } } : { labelCol: { span: 4, offset: 3 }, wrapperCol: { span: 14, offset: 3 } };

  const buttonItemLayout =
    formLayout === 'horizontal' ? { wrapperCol: { span: 14, offset: 4 } } : null;

  return (
    <Form 
      {...formItemLayout}
      layout={formLayout}
      form={form}
      initialValues={{ layout: formLayout }}
      onValuesChange={onFormLayoutChange}
      style={{ maxWidth: formLayout === 'inline' ? 'none' : 600 }}
    >
      <Form.Item   label="Form Layout" name="layout">
        <Radio.Group value={formLayout}>
          <Radio.Button value="horizontal">Horizontal</Radio.Button>
          <Radio.Button value="vertical">Vertical</Radio.Button>
          <Radio.Button value="inline">Inline</Radio.Button>
        </Radio.Group>
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item label="Field A">
        <Input placeholder="input placeholder" />
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item label="Field B">
        <Input placeholder="input placeholder" />
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item {...buttonItemLayout}>
        <Button type="primary">Submit</Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Demo of Ant Design whit Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/run?file=demo.tsx

In the above demo I have edit `formItemLayout`

From

```
    formLayout === 'horizontal' ? { labelCol: { span: 4 }, wrapperCol: { span: 14 } } : null;
```

To

```
  const formItemLayout =
    formLayout === 'horizontal' ? { labelCol: { span: 4 }, wrapperCol: { span: 14 } } : { labelCol: { span: 4, offset: 3 }, wrapperCol: { span: 14, offset: 3 } };
```